# Google Cloud Functions Notifications iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I was finishing up an app for somebody but needed some help with the script that I wrote for sending notifications via Cloud Functions for Firebase. Below this text you can find my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userUid}/').onWrite(event => {
  const followerUid = event.params.userUid;

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Update Received',
        body: 'Please Check Your App',
        badge: 1,
        sound: 1,
      }
    };

    return admin.database().ref('/Admin/notificationID').once('value').then(allTokens => {
        if (allTokens.val()) {
            // Listing all tokens.
            const tokens = allTokens.value
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {

        });
        };
    });  
});
```

Mainly there are only 3 issues that I am having. First of all, I am not sure if I am using the correct syntax for specifying the badge. Second of all, I don't know how to specify that I want a sound to be played for the notification. Lastly, I am unable to send the notification because the notificationID that is returned from the database is apparently incorrect even though I have a legible FCM ID stored in my database under /Admin/ with the key notificationID. I would appreciate it if one of you could help me fix these issues and get this app up and running.

Thanks,
KPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The value for [`badge`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) needs to be String:

> Optional, string

2. Same in #1, `sound` value needs to be String:

> Optional, string
>
> The sound to play when the device receives the notification.
>
> Sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app's data container. See the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10) for more information.

3. Hard to tell without any additional details. Are you positive that it's a valid registration token? Does it work when you send a message to it using the Firebase Console? If not, is it throwing an error?